# charset=utf-8 in @Consumes is not working

Tags: http, character-encoding, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey 2.16. For rest interface, I need to accept 'application/xml' and produce 'application/xml' with charset=utf-8. My code is,

```
@POST
@Produces("application/xml; charset=utf-8")
@Consumes("application/xml; charset=utf-8")
public String process(String request) {
 ...
return response;
```

}

Here, when I send request from Client, I set `Content-Type` as `application/xml;charset=iso-8859-1` which I expect server to throw some error as it does not match with `utf-8`. But this does not happens. However the `charset=utf-8` is set in response. Is this correct way of checking `charset` for `HTTP Request`?

Comment: Charset attribute just instruct jersey on how to encode/decode bytes, if you send data using another charset you'll get wrong chars... try to send some non ASCII chars and see what happens

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that 415 error will be thrown in case of charset mis-match. This makes things clear. I will use charset check in application. What error code must be sent in case of charset mismatch? Should it be 415?

Comment: @MaliniKennady what error are you getting currently when you do not provide charset value ?

Comment: No i dont get any error in application. My goal is to accept only request with 'utf-8' charset.

Comment: @MaliniKennady if you really want it maybe a 400 bad request according to [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1), (as 415 is more related to media type) anyway I doubt you can successful always detect if client is using a charset different than UTF-8

Comment: I use, `@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest`. Hence `servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()` returns charset sent by client. I think i can use this to check `utf-8` and return error code, possibly 400.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject directly with @HeaderParam and then validate the charset in your code.

```
public String process(@HeaderParam("Accept-Charset") String charset,  String request) {

 if (charset.equalsIgnoreCase ("utf-8"))
 {
     // do something
 }
 else
 {
   // update your response.
 }
 ...
return response;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for 'accept-type' and I was trying to check for content type charset which I currently achieve by using servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding().

Comment: @MaliniKennady correct. `@HeaderParam` will give you limited header value compared to `@Context`

Comment: Is a separate header that gives "Content-type" encoding like "Accept-Charset". As far I saw `@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String charset` gives something like `application\xml; charset=utf-8`. Here i need to parse to get `utf-8`. But using `servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()` gives `utf-8` and no need for parsing and hence I chose that.